# Random whitespace around HTML email in iOS mail app

Tags: html, ios, css, email

I have created a HTML email which is great and works fine on mobile. The only problem is that there is a strange white gap between the email and the edge of the screen. For example the image in the email should hit both sides of the screen rather than being squished in the middle.

Im using simple `table` structure the build the email e.g:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <td>content here</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have no idea what may be causing this: for those who dare to see the HTML it can be seen [here.](http://codepen.io/nognut/pen/xOVLVB?editors=1010)

As for the view from my mobile here is a preview:

[image: Mobile View]

Any idea's or help is appreciated.

Comment: Sadly, this is a "feature" of iOS 9 that doesn't yet have a fix. See [this post](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/4223-ios-9-mail-app-for-ipad-adds-padding-that-can-t-be-overridden?utm_campaign=ios9&utm_source=litmusblog&utm_medium=blog).

Comment: @4castle That's a shame. Never knew making HTML emails responsive was such a difficult task.